# Authenticate user in Selenium test

Tags: django, selenium-webdriver

I'm testing user authentication in Django project with Selenium webdriver, and created a test:

```
class EditorBlogTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def create_session_store(self):
        user = User.objects.create(email='a@b.com', username='TestUser')
        engine = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE)
        store = engine.SessionStore()
        store[SESSION_KEY] = user.pk
        store.save()
        return store

    def test_user_authenticated(self):
        store = self.create_session_store()
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + '/dashboard/')
        self.browser.add_cookie({
            'name': settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME,
            'value': store.session_key,
            'path': '/',
        })
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + '/dashboard/blog/add/')
        hello_box = self.browser.find_element_by_id('hello')

        self.assertIsNotNone(self.browser.get_cookie('sessionid'))
        self.assertEqual('Hello, TestUser', hello_box.text)
```

in template there is a line:

```
    <div id="hello">Hello, {{ user }}</div>
```

But the test failed:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_session_creation (functional_tests.dashboard.test_blog.EditorBlogTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/django/my_project/functional_tests/dashboard/test_blog.py", line 26, in test_user_authenticated
    self.assertEqual('Hello, TestUser', hello_box.text)
AssertionError: 'Hello, TestUser' != 'Hello, AnonymousUser'
- Hello, TestUser
+ Hello, AnonymousUser


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 2.406s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong with it?

Comment: Try to add the key ``path='/'`` to the ``dict`` of ``self.browser.add_cookie``

Comment: @YannicHamann I tried (updated the code) but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a deeper research of the topic and found that session has nothing to do with **RequestContext**, that contains `{{ user }}` variable (as well as the rest context). So, the easiest way to authenticate a user in Selenium test is to open login page on the site and fill the form with test user credentials. After that my test managed to pass.